# Calculating Standard Deviation on 2 Independent Random Variables and More

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, variance

This is the problem I was assigned in my homework:

[image]

I read in the textbook and believe that this method should be applied to solve the problem when dealing with 2 independent variables.

[image]

As a result, I've done so hand-written work and filled in the formula like this:

```
var(aX + bY) = 48^2 (1) + 6^2 (.0625)
```

However, as I have found incredibly weird and most likely wrong, the variance came out to be 2306.25, and thus the calculated standard deviation was **48.02**. This seems wrong to me, but I can't lay my finger on it.

**Explanation of variables and why I chose this formula**

I'm on part A, and I calculated the expected amount of ice cream to be served in total to be **48** + **3 scoops of a mean of 2 oz each** = 54 oz.

I went on to the second part of A, and came up with the formula above. Is there something wrong with how I set it up?

Edit: On Part B now

Expected value of ice cream being left in the box is: **48 - 2 = 46 oz**.
Variance formula: var(aX + bY) = 1^2 * 1 + 1^2 * .0625 = 1.0625 = **1.03**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of (a), you probably should have uses $a=1$ ("one box") <del>and b=3 ("plus three scoops from a second box")</del> in the combined variance formula.  But if the scoops are independent of each other and the box then you should be using a formula more like $Var(X+Y_1+Y_2+Y_3) = Var(X)+Var(Y_1)+Var(Y_2)+Var(Y_3)$ so here $1+0.0625+0.0625+0.0625$ *[edited - see OpalE's comment]*

You will get a more credible standard deviation.

Comment: Which works out to be 1.25.

Comment: @Henry - Then the formula looks like this: var(aX + bY) = 1^2 * 1 + 3^2 * .0625, which equals 1.5625?

Comment: @Xari Yes: though you need the square root for a standard deviation

Comment: Thank you! And this standard deviation is the amount of ice cream being served, right? In what units though? I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around the fact that I just used a unit of box with units of scoops to get a combined variance. Is the SD calculated from this ice cream in oz, or just ice cream in total? @Henry

Comment: Mean and standard deviation are usually measured in the same units (in the case of the box and the scoops, the table uses fluid ounces for mean and SD) and the square of that for variance

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. I plan on working through the rest of this problem and clarifying whether or not I'm doing it correctly. If you're willing, I updated the problem above and am solving part B and have listed what I have done so far. Does this seem correct to you? If so, then I should be able to finish the rest of the problem @Henry

Comment: I'm concerned that since each scoop is itself randomly sampled, you might possibly be needing to use more than 2 independent variables: I think you should have 3 independent scoops represented as Y1, Y2, and Y3. Refer to this AP Statistics problem from several years back: http://media.collegeboard.com/digitalServices/pdf/ap/apcentral/ap13_statistics_q3.pdf (part ii). This would result in you NOT squaring the 3.

Comment: @OpalE I see what you're saying. Instead of needing to square it you just add up the variances independently like ... var(B) + var(B) + var(B) because they are all independent from one another. And thus, it becomes .0625 * 3?

Comment: That is my thought. Since it would make sense that each scoop was independent from the previous (for the most part).

Comment: @OpalE: I suspect you are correct, so I will edit my answer